# Changing SqlDataSource.SelectCommand at runtime breaks pagination

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination, sqldatasource, selectcommand

I have a `GridView` bound to a `SqlDataSource` with a default `SelectCommand` defined as such:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConn %>" 
      ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
      SelectCommand="select * from blah blah" />
```

There are cases where I have to change this query dynamically at runtime, so I do the following:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql; // 'sql' is the new query
GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
GridView1.DataBind();
updatePanel.Update();
```

This works just fine actually, but when I click the pagination controls, the result set defaults back to the `SelectCommand` defined in the `SqlDataSource1`.

Any way around this?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that the SqlDataSource is getting re-created when the page loads upon the submit issued by the Pager links. There is nothing to tell it to load what you had set dynamically. If you were to use a stored procedure with parameters then ASP would save off the parameters to ViewState and re-run the select in the SqlDataSource when the page loaded.

So what you have to do is tell the the SqlDataSource what it had for SQL when it last loaded correctly.

The simplest way to do that is to store the SQL in ViewState when you set the SelectCommand of the SqlDataSource and then retrieve it again in the Page_Load event and set it back.

For instance: Let's say you have a TextBox for some criteria and a Search button. When the user enters some text into the TextBox and then clicks on the "Search" button, you want it to build up some SQL (This, by the way, leaves you with a huge exposure to SQL Injection attacks. Make sure you scrub your criteria well.) and then set the SqlDataSource's SelectCommand property. It is a t this point that you would want to save off the SQL. Then in the Page_Load event you would want to retrieve it and set the SelectCommand property to that value.

In the Click of your button you could store the SQL:

```
Dim sSQL as String

sSQL = "SELECT somefields FROM sometable WHERE somefield = '" & Me.txtCriteria.Text & "'"
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sSQL
ViewState("MySQL") = sSQL
```

Then in the Page_Load event you could retrieve the SQL and set the SelectCommand property:

```
Dim sSQL as String

If Me.IsPostBack() Then
    sSQL = ViewState("MySQL")
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sSQL
End If
```

Comment: -1 This approach is prone to SQL Injection and is not recommended. You should use parameters, not string concatenation.

Comment: Mike, you are correct about the SQL injection and I did note that in the original response. I was merely trying to answer the question that was asked. I also agree that using a stored procedure with parameters is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try set datasource from the page preview, not dynamically. This is the most clear solution
If you can't,

2) Try to generate the list before page_load. I think placing code under page_init might do the trick. I can't remember exactly at the moment, but there is a method before page_load.