# how to set passing variable in SelectCommand Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

**i try this example but not working.**

```
<%string id = Request.QueryString["id"]; %>// get value and set in one variable
<%=id%>// display successfully variable's value
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [name], [image], [old_price], [new_price] FROM [product] where [id]= "'<%=id%>'"" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**a problem in SelectCommand how to set variable in query i try like <%=id%>**

Comment: a problem in SelectCommand how to set variable in query i try like <%=id%>.

Comment: I warmly suggest you NOT to mix the presentation layer of your app with the data layer. There are tons of reasons. Among them, security, logic decoupling, maintenance. Please, do not do that. For further details on the SelectCommand, please check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This link might help you ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319358/changing-sqldatasource-selectcommand-at-runtime-breaks-pagination

Comment: i am not display a database in gridview. in normal html table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the codebehind, for example in the [`Selecting` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ... OnSelecting="Product_Selecting">
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Product_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters[0].Value = Request.QueryString["id"];
}
```